# How to Update Reimers Google Analytics Reader

Tags: .net, google-analytics-api

I've been using Jacob Reimers popular [Analytics Reader](http://www.reimers.dk/jacob-reimers-blog/added-google-analytics-reader-for-net) for .Net. Last week I noticed that it was no longer working and kept throwing an error.  After doing research, I found that it is related to the requestUrlFormat variable: "https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/" which is no longer supported by google.  Does anyone know how to modify the code so that it won't throw an error?

Answer (score 1):

Another user reported the same issue, and was good enough to provide a patch as well. The problem is that Google changed the service URL. If you pull down the latest source code (svn://svn.reimers.dk/Reimers.Google) and build the project it should work again. Otherwise ping me though the contact information on the site.

Comment: Thanks so much! When I looked at the article source code, I didn't see any code changes.  I'll let you know if the code still has issues.  Otherwise, no news will be good news! Lol

Comment: I didn't actually update the article because you can download the source code from the SVN repo link I gave in the answer. It's true I need to update the article, but I never find the time :-)